# Error with 'from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo'

Tags: python-2.7

I'm reading a financial book about Python.  In the book the author is importing historical stock prices from yahoo finance.  The very first line of code:

```
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo
```

Causes the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo
ImportError: cannot import name quotes_historical_yahoo
```

I went to this link and downloaded the zipped file.

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

I unzipped everything into this folder:

```
C:\Python27\matplotlib
```

I opened the CMD window, naviagted to that folder, and entered this:

```
python setup.py install
```

That gives me this error.

[image]

Even the traditional pip install doesn't work for me.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?  I'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `python` in your `PATH`?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I took that out and used this instead: setup.py install
It looks like everything installs, but I'm still getting the original error.